# Output of text2people from http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/

Tags: text-mining

I just installed the [data toolkit](http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/) and run text2people from the command line on files and a couple of web pages.

As output, I get something like

```
Peter Williams,Peter,Williams,,m,151431,151445,stdin
David Philippaerts,David,Philippaerts,,m,152500,152518,stdin
Da Ryse,Da,Ryse,,m,158551,158558,stdin
```

I can guess that the first fields are name, surname and sex, but I couldn't understand how to get the other info shown in the [website](http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/developerdocs), like ethnicity. Should I use it via python/javascript etc.?
Help and documentation are really minimal ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and extract the python_tools.zip. If you installed the libraries to your OS, you can create your program where you want, otherwise you can just write your test program to the directory where dstk.py is located.

Here's a simple test program. It has a list of people whose information it fetches from the service. It will then go through their ethnicity information and prints their most likely ethnicity along with its percentage.

```
import dstk
from pprint import pprint

dstk = dstk.DSTK()

# List of people you want to search for
people_names = ["Samuel L. Jackson", "Michelle Yeoh", "Danny Trejo", "Vanessa Minnillo","Naomi Campbell","Chuck Norris"]

# Query information for each person in the list
people = dstk.text2people(",".join(people_names))

# Print the structure of the received information
#print people

# Prints the structure of the people in more readable way
#pprint(people)

# Print name and ethnicity information of person
for person in people:

    if person['ethnicity'] == None:
        print (person['first_name'] + " " + person['surnames']).ljust(26), "Unknown ethnicity"
    else:
        ethnics = ['percentage_american_indian_or_alaska_native','percentage_asian_or_pacific_islander','percentage_black','percentage_hispanic','percentage_two_or_more','percentage_white']
        highest_probability = 0
        highest_index = 0

        # Find highest percentage
        for eth_index in ethnics:
            if person['ethnicity'][eth_index] > highest_probability:
                highest_probability = person['ethnicity'][eth_index]
                highest_index = eth_index
        print (person['first_name'] + " " + person['surnames']).ljust(20), str(person['ethnicity'][highest_index]).ljust(5), highest_index
```

The code above will print the following:

```
Samuel L Jackson     53.02 percentage_black
Michelle Yeoh        87.74 percentage_asian_or_pacific_islander
Danny Trejo          94.15 percentage_hispanic
Vanessa Minnillo           Unknown ethnicity
Naomi Campbell       76.47 percentage_white
Chuck Norris         82.01 percentage_white
```

You can see the names of the variables by printing the structure you receive from the server (`pprint(people)`), and the names are quite obvious.

I had a hard time finding anyone who would be counted as multiraced or american indian. The database seems to insist they're white.